# Registered User counter

Tags: php, connection, counter

Ok so have this code that is supposed to show the users name and then show the number of registered users. So my problem is that is shows the users name but won't show the number of users. I keep getting this error.

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/68/10509868/html/login-home.php on line 147

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/content/68/10509868/html/login-home.php on line 147
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

**AND this is my code that works.**

Welcome back `<?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>`!

**And this is my code that doesn't seem to work** 
We have

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("select * FROM users")or die(mysql_error());
$nrows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

echo $nrows;
?>
```

registered users now!

And this is how I connect to my database

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host IP","username","password");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: First you have to check if your mysql is running, also your conncetion is with mysqli extensio and your querys is with mysql...you have to use one but no both and my advice use mysqli extension to take advantage of prepare statement

Answer (score 1):

MySQLi and MySQL are different libraries.  mysql_query is a command used with the MySQL library (and which is being deprecated) but you are connecting using the MySQLi libarary.  Do do a query with MySQLi you should look at the PHP manual here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Comment: `<?php
$con=mysql_connect("IP","username","password");
**line 131** if (mysql_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
  }
?>` So now that I've changed from using both connection points ,I get an error on line 131 which states the following `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect_errno()`

Comment: Ok I've changed mysql_connect_errno($con)) to mysql_errno($con)) and now I get no erros but it says no database selected. After ,"password" I have also added the name of the database I'm trying to connect to named goaldoctor